# Adobe Camera Raw custom settings can be saved, but saved presets don't work or can't be read

Tags: adobe-photoshop, windows-domain, folder-redirection, camera-raw

Photoshop 2021 or 2023, updated Adobe Camera Raw.

I open some raws in ACR, ctrl+S to save, and let's say I change settings to jpeg, 1080p, sharpen. Save that as a preset and name it preset-1.

Then I change some settings, TIFF at 16 bit, no resize. Save that as preset-2.

What happens is, any preset I click will immediately revert to whatever my current settings are. So I'm on preset-2, I click the dropdown and change to preset-1, and immediately that dropdown changes to "custom" and no settings change whatsoever. This happens no matter how many presets I make.

I'm in an office on a domain with folder redirection turned on. So I can go to e.g. *C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\CameraRaw*

but photoshop's files are really being saved in
*\\server\UserDir\myname\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CameraRaw*

Deleting both camera raw preferences, and save options, will forget all my saved options and preferences as expected, but it doesn't stop the problem. I also gave full permissions to 'everyone' on all files and subfolders in \adobe\ and made my account the owner but it doesn't help. I'm guessing folder redirection is still the culprit. I could reinstall locally but it's a pain and I'm hoping to work within the paramaters of our domain.

Any ideas?